# Changing textbox border and background on validation fail

Tags: asp.net, css, textbox

is it possible to use javascript so that when an asp.net validator fails (for example the input doesnt match the regex), the textbox border and background color changes to a shade of red. Iv seen this before, but i forgot where.

Can someone please link me to a live example of such?

And a way i can do this?

Thanks

Edit:

Using this solution:

```
validateField = function(sender, args){        
    //do your validation logic        
    if (!args.IsValid){
        var ctrl = $("#" + sender.controltovalidate);
        if (ctrl){
            ctrl.css({ "background-color" : "#990000", "border" : "1px solid #993300" });
        }
    }
    return args.IsValid;
}
```

If i where to use regular exressions, is this the correct way to do it?

```
validateField = function(sender, args){        
    var regEx=(some regex forumla)
    if (sender.value.search(regEx)==-1)        
        var ctrl = $("#" + sender.controltovalidate);
        if (ctrl){
            ctrl.css({ "background-color" : "#990000", "border" : "1px solid #993300" });
        }
    }
   else
        {
           return args.IsValid;
         }
}
```

Sorry for my lack of knowledge, iv never used javascript before. Also, what is the:

```
 return args.IsValid;
```

At the end for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CustomValidator`, and if validation fails you can change the border and background colors in the client-side validation function:

Validation function:

```
validateField = function(sender, args){        
    //do your validation logic        
    if (!args.IsValid){
        var ctrl = $("#" + sender.controltovalidate);
        if (ctrl){
            ctrl.css({ "background-color" : "#990000", "border" : "1px solid #993300" });
        }
    }
    return args.IsValid;
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" EnableClientScript="true"
    ErrorMessage="Required"
    ClientValidationFunction="validateField" 
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
    Display="Dynamic">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: Thanks, i like this solution. IF i use the javascript to validate, do i need to also write a c# validator for use on the server side?

Comment: You can specify a server-side validation function with the `CustomValidator` control.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this

```
    Private Sub HighlightInvalidFields()

    For Each validator As IValidator In Page.Validators
        If TypeOf validator Is BaseValidator Then
            If CType(validator, BaseValidator).IsValid = False Then

                Dim controlId As String = CType(validator, BaseValidator).ControlToValidate
                Dim control As WebControl = TryCast(Me.FindControlRecursive(controlId), WebControl)

                If control IsNot Nothing Then
                    control.Style.Add("background-color", "#B85449")
                End If

            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I call it from the page_prerender

```
    Private Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    If Page.IsPostBack Then HighlightInvalidFields()
End Sub
```

Comment: It may be helpful to note that I have a base class that I Inherit System.Web.UI.Page, so this code is not replicated on each page, I just have every page inherit from the base page.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ChangeColorPage : Page {
public Label lblZip;
public RegularExpressionValidator valZip;

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {     
    Page.Validate();       
    lblZip.ForeColor = valZip.IsValid? Color.Black : Color.Red;
    }               
}


<asp:Label id=lblZip runat=server Text="Zip Code:"/> 
<asp:TextBox id=txtZip runat=server OnChange="txtZipOnChange();" /></asp:TextBox><br>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id=valZip runat=server ControlToValidate=txtZip ErrorMessage="Invalid Zip Code" ValidationExpression="[0-9]{5}" /><br>

<script language=javascript>
function txtZipOnChange() {
   // Do nothing if client validation is not active
   if (typeof(Page_Validators) == "undefined")  return;
   // Change the color of the label
   lblZip.style.color = valZip.isvalid ? "Black" : "Red";
}
</script>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx